# I need to prove that $Z^{n}=r^{n}(\cos n\theta +i\sin n\theta)$ is true by Induction. Can someone confirm whether I have done it right or not?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, induction

The equation $$Z^{n}=r^{n}(\cos(n\theta) +i\sin(n\theta))\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space (1)$$ has to be proved by induction. It is given that  $$Z=r(\cos(\theta) +i\sin(\theta)).\space$$ I first proved (1) true for $n=1$. This gives $$Z=r(\cos(\theta) +i\sin(\theta)).\space$$ This is true as it was given. Next I assumed (1) to be true for $n=q.$ This implies $$Z^{q}=r^{q}(\cos(q\theta) +i\sin(q\theta)).$$ Then I proved (1) to be true for $n=q+1$. This implied; $$Z^{q+1}=r^{q+1}(\cos(q\theta+\theta)) +i\sin(q\theta+\theta)),$$ 
$$\implies Z^{q}\cdot Z=(r(\cos(\theta) +i\sin(\theta)))^{q+1},\space by\space De\space Moivre's\space Theorem,$$
$$\implies Z^{q}\cdot Z=(r(\cos(\theta) +i\sin(\theta)))^{q}\cdot r(\cos(\theta) +i\sin(\theta)), $$
$$\implies Z^{q}=(r(\cos(\theta) +i\sin(\theta)))^{q},$$
$$\implies Z^{q}=r^{q}(\cos(q\theta) +i\sin(q\theta)).$$

Hence (1) has been proven true for $n=q+1$.

Comment: You cannot use De Moivre′s Theorem to prove De Moivre′s Theorem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, no. You cannot write like that.

Assume that it holds for $n=q$, i.e.
$$Z^q=r^q(\cos(q\theta)+i\sin(q\theta)).$$
Then, we have
$$\begin{align}Z^{q+1}&=Z\cdot Z^q\\&=r(\cos\theta+i\sin \theta)\cdot r^q(\cos(q\theta)+i\sin(q\theta))\\&=r^{q+1}((\cos\theta\cos(q\theta)-\sin\theta\sin(q\theta))+i(\cos\theta\sin(q\theta)+\sin\theta\cos(q\theta)))\\&=r^{q+1}(\cos(\theta+q\theta)+i\sin(\theta+q\theta))\\&=r^{q+1}(\cos((q+1)\theta)+i\sin((q+1)\theta)).\end{align}$$
Hence, it holds for $n=q+1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain why my answer above is wrong?

Comment: @Jnyeboah93: As others pointed, you cannot use De Moivre′s Theorem to prove De Moivre′s Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The question asks us to **prove** the validity of the de Moivre Formula, and the proposed proof **uses**  the de Moivre Formula.

For the induction step you are expected to multiply $\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)$ by $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ in the natural way, and then quote certain trigonometric addition laws.